# "Информация о прогнозе погоды." Не словом единым?

Tags: сестра-таланта

Словосочетание это незаметно стало звуком. Больше - шумом, чем звуком. И шум тот не наш.

Answer (score 2):

Если за этим следует прогноз погоды, то так говорить не стоит, но выражение возможное - лишь бы употреблялось к месту.

Информация о прогнозе погоды: прогноз будет дан вечером в 18:00.

Comment: Информация о прогнозе погоды: прогноз будет дан вечером в 18:00.

Мудрёно. Имеется ввиду, что смысл информации заключён в указании времени передачи? Значит, есть шанс, что о выходе следующей передачи мы услышим что-то вроде: "Информация о сказке для малышей: сказка для них прозвучит в 18:10".

Comment: Добавлю: смотрите метку. Проблема - не столько в странной связке "информация - прогноз", что очевидно, но в количестве слов при невеликой смысловой задаче. Если избавится от иностранной "воды" (ничего личного, просто так совпало), останется то, что нужно: О погоде.